# 2-term weak algorithm implies weak-algorithm?

Tags: ring-theory

So I was reading the book "free rings and their relations" to see a criteria for free algebras. In this book, it's introduced the concept of n-term weak algorithm. In page 78, it's shown that if $R_0$ is a division ring than $R$ must have a weak algebra basis. It can be shown that if $R$ satisfies the $2$-term weak algorithm then $R_0$ must be a division ring.

To conclude, it's shown that $R$ satisfies the weak algorithm iff $R_0$ is a division ring and has a weak algebra basis.

So, by this, we can conclude that if $R$ satisfies the $2$-weak algorithm then $R_0$ is a division ring and therefore $R$ has a weak algebra basis. It means that $R$ satisfies the weak algorithm.

I can't see where the mistake is (or what I've understood wrong).